# Deny normal users to access administrator area in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, authorization, roles

Okay so I have two folders in my ASP.NET project. One is for users, and the other one is for administrators... The idea is that once the normal user logs into the system via his username & password, he won't be able to access the admin folder. I was thinking something like this would work:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="admins"/>
      <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

But I'm having issues on how to mark the normal as normal, and administrator as admin so that normal user can't access admin area (folder)? I believe this could be done through the code while the normal user logs into the system, but how??

Can someone help me out with this ?

P.S. the database tables for admins and users are separated in my case...

Comment: Have a look into asp.net Membership and Role provider. Good article to start you of [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/281573/ASP-NET-Membership-and-Role-Provider)